# SQL Server CE: SET DATEFIRST not working

Tags: sql-server-ce, week-number, datepart

I'm using SQL Server CE for rapid application development purposes and have hit a little snag - it doesn't seem to support changing the start day of the week.

What I've tried:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
```

which yields: `Unrecognized SET statement` as a response (both via a query window and through code).  I've googled around and can't find anything in the documentation as to whether changing the start date of a week is supported or isn't supported by SQL Server Ce, nor can I find any alternative method of changing this.

Am I doing something stupid, or can anyone confirm that this isn't supported (or perhaps both?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supported - why not just fix in C# code?

Comment: OK, good to know - I recognise you as the expert in CE so, anyone else reading this, this is as good as gold.  Regarding fixing in C# code, I've several levels of abstraction between c# and the query and it's not worth broadening the abstraction layers to deal with this special case.  I'll live with it.  Thank you.

Comment: @ErikEJ Would this be a complicated thing to fix in C# code?