# SQL how to use DATEFIRST with razor

Tags: sql, sql-server, razor, datepart

I've figured out that `DATEPART` by default starts the week on a sunday. Where I'm from we don't do that, we start the week on monday.

I found that to change the start day I could use `DATEFIRST 1`, however I don't know how to implement it.

Mostly because whenever I see SQL code on here its formated like the following.

```
SELECT 
    date, name
FROM 
    Column
WHERE 
    date = @0
```

but I do it like this

```
var query = "SELECT date, name FROM Column WHERE date = @0";
```

just an example.

I don't really know how to use the first version of my example so I always convert it to how I use it, however I'm not sure what to do with `SET DATEFIRST 1` so that the database will use it and start my weeks on mondays.

I want to do it on the following query.

```
var query = "SELECT DATEPART(wk, date) as wknumber, sum((kg * rep * sett)) as weight, sum(kg / max * rep * sett) as avg, sum((rep * sett)) as reps, max(kg / max) as peak FROM Test WHERE date between @0 and @1 AND exercise < 4 GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, date)";
```

Comment: I'd normally recommend against using `DATEFIRST` and trying to avoid writing code that depends on any particular value for that setting. I can't see an obvious simple transformation in this case but it's the direction I'd aim for.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve that by adding SET DATEFIRST 1 in the beginning of your query and separated by semicolon ";"

```
var query = "SET DATEFIRST 1; SELECT ... FROM Column WHERE date = @0";
```

**Updated**:
Why don't you just get the date and find the week number in the code

Comment: Gave me "Unrecognized SET statement."

Comment: Are you using ADO.net ?

Comment: SQL server compact, and razor

Comment: SQL server compact does not support SET DATEFIRST. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177819/sql-server-ce-set-datefirst-not-working

Comment: And thats not the query I want to do it on, thats just an example I used to make a point, I want to do it on the following query with DATEPART(wk, date) and that shows my data in weekly sums, but from sunday to saturday instead of monday to sunday, so I dont know how you mean by getting the date?